# Selecting the correct AppPool in PerfMon instances

Tags: .net, asp.net, performance, perfmon, performance-monitor

I have a webserver with six App Pools. When I want to add counters in PerfMon for a specific ASP.NET application, the available instances have very different names.

For example, I have an App Pool named “FrontEnd”, and these are the instances available:

> _LM_W3SVC_1_Root_bookeline
>   _LM_W3SVC_1_Root_CredentialsService
>   _LM_W3SVC_1_Root_pReports
>   _LM_W3SVC_1130837766_Root
>   _LM_W3SVC_1147758436_Root
>   _LM_W3SVC_1254277584_Root
>   _LM_W3SVC_1366866887_Root
>   _LM_W3SVC_1505760911_Root
>   _LM_W3SVC_1604538730_Root
>   _LM_W3SVC_1618350214_Root
>   _LM_W3SVC_175082253_Root
>   _LM_W3SVC_177047044_Root
>   _LM_W3SVC_1825997120_ROOT
>   _LM_W3SVC_1966585210_Root
>   _LM_W3SVC_204756873_Root
>   _LM_W3SVC_261753984_Root
>   _LM_W3SVC_3_ROOT
>   _LM_W3SVC_315617261_Root
>   _LM_W3SVC_36575378_Root
>   _LM_W3SVC_575979470_Root
>   _LM_W3SVC_831033229_Root
>   _LM_W3SVC_940052100_Root

A colleague suggested a neat trick to match the App Pools to Process IDs by creating a small .bat file:

> c:\windows\system32\cscript.exe c:\windows\system32\iisapp.vbs
>   pause

However those ID’s doesn’t seem to have anything to do with the instances either.

What am I misunderstanding here?

Answer (score 2):

Look closely to your instance names: `_LM_W3SVC_1147758436_Root` number `1147758436` here is your application identifier, which can be found in IIS Manager.

[image]

Good news are that this identifier do not changes after application, iis or server restart unlike PID

Answer (score 0):

We use a utility from SysInternals called BGInfo.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897557

You can configure it to show your AppPools and associated process IDs. Check out this screenshot (background from the server).

[image: Server Screenshot with BGInfo]

[@arcain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/210774/arcain?tab=stats) pointed out that we are using a custom configuration to get BGInfo to print the app pools. Here it is.

```
Host Name:  <Host Name>
User Name:  <User Name>
Boot Time:  <Boot Time>
Snapshot Time:  <Snapshot Time>

IP Address: <IP Address>
Subnet Mask:    <Subnet Mask>
Default Gateway:    <Default Gateway>
DNS Server: <DNS Server>
MAC Address:    <MAC Address>


Volumes:    <Volumes>
Free Space: <Free Space>

IIS App Pools:  <IIS App Pools>

IE Version: <IE Version>

CPU:    <CPU>
Memory: <Memory>
Network Card:   <Network Card>
Network Speed:  <Network Speed>
OS Version: <OS Version>
Service Pack:   <Service Pack>
System Type:    <System Type>
```

Comment: Michael:  Can you give a little more information on how to use this custom config in BGInfo?  The Custom Configuration (Define New Field) screen asks you what kind of configuration -- Env. Variables, VB Script Files, Registry, WMI... and then asks you to specify a path to it.  How do you do that for the application pools?

Answer (score 0):

Using [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx), 
hover over a w3wp.exe process, you will see the command line that started it with the app-pool name there. The same view that shows the process name has the pid to verify against what perfmon shows.